# Geolocation isSuccessful getter showing error

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation

I am trying to create a project on flutter using Geolocation plugin.
But 'result' variable of type Geolocation is not working fine. I am using getter 'isSuccessfull' of result type. It is throwing error displaying that no such  getter exist.How can I get rid of this problem.Please help.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
    import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';
    import 'package:geolocation/geolocation.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(new MyCurrentLocationMap());
    }

    class MyCurrentLocationMap extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyCurrentLocationMapState createState() => _MyCurrentLocationMapState();
    }

    class _MyCurrentLocationMapState extends State<MyCurrentLocationMap> {
      MapController mapController = new MapController();

      getPermission() async {
        final GeolocationResult result =
            await Geolocation.requestLocationPermission(
                permission: const LocationPermission(
                    android: LocationPermissionAndroid.fine,
                    ios: LocationPermissionIOS.always));
        return result;

      }

      getLocation() {
        return getPermission().then((result) {
          if (result.isSuccessful) {
            final coords =
                Geolocation.currentLocation(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
            print(coords);
            return coords;
          }
        });
      }

      dynamic lat, long;

      buildMap() {
        getLocation().then((response) {
          if (response.isSuccessful) {
            response.listen((value) {
              mapController.move(
                  new LatLng(value.location.latitude, value.location.longitude),
                  15.0);

              lat = value.location.latitude;
              long = value.location.longitude;
            });
          }
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
          home: new Scaffold(
            body: new FlutterMap(
              mapController: mapController,
              options: MapOptions(
                minZoom: 100.0,
                center: buildMap(),
              ),
              layers: [
                new TileLayerOptions(
                    urlTemplate:
                        "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                    subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
                 new MarkerLayerOptions(markers: [
                   new Marker(
                       width: 45.0,
                       height: 45.0,
                       point: new LatLng(lat, long),
                       builder: (context) => new Container(
                             child: IconButton(
                               icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                               color: Colors.blue,
                               iconSize: 45.0,
                               onPressed: () {
                                 print("Market tapped");
                               },
                             ),
                           ))
                 ])
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

pubspec.yaml

```
    name: helloWorld
    description: A new Flutter project.

    publish_to: 'none' 

    CFBundleVersion.
    # Read more about iOS versioning at
    # https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
    version: 1.0.0+1

    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      flutter_circular_chart:
      flutter_map:
      geolocation: ^1.0.0

     
      cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
      http: ^0.12.0
      

    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter

    
    flutter:

     


      fonts:
      
        - family: bebas-neue
          fonts:
            - asset: assets/BebasNeue-Regular.ttf
```

The following link shows the error image
https://pasteboard.co/JLg7jra.png

Comment: Sorry, but unfortunately, that's not the solution you have posted. Its not working..still showing same error.Please help if u can

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined your `getPermission`method to return a specific datatype. You probably want it to return a `GeolocationResult`:

```
Future<GeolocationResult> getPermission() async {
```

Your `getLocation` is also not doing what you think it is doing. This is not JavaScript, so please treat it like an actual programming language. Declare your types and the compiler will help you with good error messages.